# NFS mount is readonly after NFS server reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, nfs

I have mounted nfs drive on `/data`, but even root user can not write to it. On nfs server I can easily read and write but any client can't. That started when nfs server went down for few minutes.

**/etc/fstab (all nfs clients):**

```
192.168.1.12:/data /data nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=0,hard,timeo=600,noac 0 0
```

**/etc/exports (nfs server):**

```
/data           192.168.1.10(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) \
                192.168.1.11(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) \
                192.168.1.12(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) \
                192.168.1.13(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

**Example:**

```
matjazmav@mav-ubuntu-01:~$ sudo su
root@mav-ubuntu-01:/home/matjazmav# touch /data/test/test.log
touch: cannot touch '/data/test/test.log': Permission denied
root@mav-ubuntu-01:/home/matjazmav# ls -al /data/test/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  3 19:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  3 19:19 ..
```